# Question about deadlocks in terms of Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, deadlock, rdbms

Can someone please explain to me the following situation:

I am using Postgresql 12 as main rdbms in my project, there are several background jobs accessing and writing to the database in parallel, also there are some user interactions (which of course produce updates and inserts to the database from the front of application)

Periodically i am getting exceptions like this one:

```
SQLSTATE[40P01]: Deadlock detected: 7 ERROR:  deadlock detected
DETAIL:  Process 18046 waits for ShareLock on transaction 212488; blocked by process 31036.
Process 31036 waits for ShareLock on transaction 212489; blocked by process 18046.
HINT:  See server log for query details.
CONTEXT:  while updating tuple (1637,16) in relation "my_table"
```

Inside my application i don't lock manually any rows or tables during my transactions. But i have 'large' transactions that can modify a lot of rows in single operation frequently. So the questions are:

1. Does ordinary transactions produce table-wide locks, or row-wide locks? (I assume yes, unless this whole situation is magic)
2. Shouldn't the rdbms resolve automatically this kind of problems when two queries are trying to modify the same resource, if they are wrapped inside transaction?
3. If answer to the second question is "no" then how i should handle that kind of situations?

Comment: Hi Have you found any solution?

Answer (score 3):

re 1) DML statements only lock the rows that are modified. There is no lock escalation in Postgres where the whole table is locked for writes. There is a "table lock" but that is only there to prevent concurrent DDL - a SELECT will also acquire that. Those share locks don't prevent DML on the table.

re 2) no, the DBMS can not resolve this because a deadlock means tx1 is waiting for a lock to be released from tx2 and tx2 is waiting for a lock to be released by tx1. How would the DBMS know what to do? The only way the DBMS can solve this is by choosing one of the two sessions as a victim and kill the transaction (which is the error you see).

re 3) the usual approach to avoiding deadlocks is to always update rows in the same order. Which usually turns the deadlock into a simple "lock wait" for the second transaction.

Assume the following UPDATE sequence

```
tx1                tx2
-------------------------------
update id = 1  |   
               | update id = 2
update id = 2  |               
(tx1 waits)    |
               | update id = 1 
                 (now we have a deadlock)
```

If you always update the rows in e.g. ascending order this changes to:

```
tx1                tx2
-------------------------------
update id = 1    |   
                 | update id = 1
                 | (waits) 
update id = 2    |               
                 |
                 |
commit;          |
(locks released) |
                 |
                 | update id = 2 
                 | commit;
```

So you don't get a deadlock, just a wait for the second transaction.

Comment: Thx for reply, but i actually can't reorder transactions to match parallel execution, because i don't know which entities will be modified by user. E.g. i have update table set col = ? where id 1 or i will have where id = 100, while background transactions locking whole 100 rows for update in one transaction, so i guess this is the reason i am getting that error

Answer (score 1):

1. All SQL statements that affect tables will take a lock on the table (albeit not necessarily a strong one). But that doesn't seem to be your problem here.

   All SQL statements that modify a row (or `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE`) will lock the affected rows. Your two transactions probably blocked on a row-level lock.
2. Yes; that is what the error message shows. PostgreSQL has resolved the deadlock by killing one of the involved transactions.

   If transactoin 1 holds a lock that transaction 2 is waiting for and vice versa, there is no other way to resolve the situation. The only way to release a lock is to end the transaction that holds it.
3. You should catch the error on your application code and retry the database transaction. A deadlock is a transient error.

   If you get a lot of deadlocks, you should try to reduce them. What helps is to keep your transactions short and small. If that is not an option, make sure that all transactions that lock several rows lock them in the same order.

Comment: Thx for reply. I am getting very small amount of deadlocks, approx 1 in 50000-60000 update transactions, but that is strictly tied to user interactions, when updates from frontend matches background jobs on same table\rows, and the problem enhances with that i can't reorder entities because i don't know what entities will be updated from user.

Comment: You don't have a database transaction open while waiting for user input, right? Then you know all affected rows when you start the transaction and can process them in a certain order. But maybe it would be easiest to simply retry the transaction when you encounter a deadlock.

Comment: Yes, of course i can do that, simply by try catching and retrying transaction, but i can not fundamentally understand this situation... Following logic above - every concurrent transactions acquiring locks in different order for same entity at the same time - will result in a deadlock, how then true high load applications work, having thousands transactions on different shards every second, this just don't feel right. Maybe i can simply lock the whole table while background jobs are running thus make every other frontend transaction wait? But this don't feel right either

Comment: Applications that have a lot of concurrent DML typically have very small transactions that affect very few rows, and they make sure to lock rows in a certain order. Nobody ever said concurrency is trivial.